# How to sync system time with a big delta in C

Tags: c, time, libc

i am working on a NTP v4 client, and i wanted to know how i can adjust system time accordingly.

i found [`adjtime(3)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/adjtime.3.html) which basically adjust's the system clock's speed by some amount thus the system clock slowly approaches the `delta` passed to the function.

but the manpage for the function states:

> `adjtime()` is intended to be used to make small adjustments to the system time.  Most systems impose a limit on the adjustment that can be specified in delta.  In the glibc implementation, delta must be less than or equal to (INT_MAX / 1000000 - 2) and greater than or equal to (INT_MIN / 1000000 + 2) (respectively `2145` and `-2145` seconds on i386).

which means i cannot make the adjustments to system time by more than `35.75` minutes in future or past on a i386 system.

but i also want to handle the case where system time is out of sync by more than `35.75` minutes or hours, days or years, without causing the running applications to misbehave.

Comment: Not positive, but my best guess is settimeofday, but it is dangerous to warp the time on a running system most of the time.  Okay at startup.

Comment: There are open-source NTP clients, why don't you see how they handle this situation?